# Statistics: Reconciling with different variance and expectation formulas

Tags: statistics

I am trying to understand these two definitions, but I'm just not clear where they come from and how they relate to the old formulas that I was used to a week ago.

In one book variance is defined as: 
$\displaystyle Var(X) = \int (x-\mu)^2 f(x) dx $ and in the other variance is $E[(X-\mu)^2]$. How are these two the same? Can someone also explain this formula: $\displaystyle \mu = \int xf(x) dx$?

Comment: Where did you find the definition of the variance as $E[(x-\mu)^2]$? That is, can you provide a specific reference (book author(s), title, publisher, and possibly page number)?  Be **very very careful** in making sure that you do NOT mix $X$ and $x$ when you copy the formula from that book; they have different meanings.

Comment: I corrected the typo. Yes I do know that $X$ represents a random variable.

Comment: Read about the [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) to understand why $$E[g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx$$ for a _continuous_ random variable (other kinds too if care is taken in the definition) in general. Then, set $g(X) = (X-\mu)^2]$